# interacting between 2 FrameLayout

Tags: android, navigation, android-framelayout

any Android code example of interacting between 2 FrameLayout or a list of parent Buttons and a FrameLayout?

1. add child Activity to bottom (main) FrameLayout
2. show iOS like push animation when new Child Activity is added

==============

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" ><Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B4" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B5" />

</LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"><TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="placeholder" />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you do normally ... what kind of code..do u want to generate dynamic layouts or images something after every button click ???

Comment: i want to load activities( which shall be static classes ) into the FrameLayout;
main purpose is to keep a custom top bar and a custom bottom bar unchanged while changing the content of FrameLayout

Comment: the above only show top navigation / tab button bar, but if it work, we are going to add bottom bar as well.